# ScrollView, EditText

Tags: android

Имеется разметка экрана которая содержит верх, середину ( ListView в нем есть несколько элементов EditView ) и низ.
Проблема огромная заключается в том что при клике на EditView клавиатура поднимает RelativeLayout со всем содержимым...

Answer (score 2):

Нужно прописать в AndroidManifest.xml для активити, где ваш EditText такую строчку: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan". Клавиатура будет поверх разметки.

Answer (score 2):

По дефолту, если есть скроллящийся элемент в лэйауте (`ListView` напр.), лэйаут должен ресайзиться при открытии IME. Если нет - "подниматься", уползать вверх, делая часть лэйаута невидимой.

Переписывается атрибутом активити в манифесте: [`android:windowSoftInputMode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).
Глянь варианты по ссылке, на мой взгляд, самый подходящий — как раз ресайз.
Однако — раз он у тебя автоматом не срабатывает, несмотря на наличие листвью — выставь явно:

```
<activity ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    ...
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если высота лэйаута задекларирована как `match_parent` то клава должна вылезать поверх

Более подробно: если иерархия лэйаутов такая: `LinearLayout->ListView` то высоту `LinearLayout` и `ListView` надо декларировать как `match_parent`