# Закрепить кнопку внизу экрана так, чтобы она не смещалась вверх при открытии клавиатуры

Tags: android

```
<!--accept button...-->
<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/common_small_button_height"
    android:text="@string/button_request_promo_code"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="@dimen/common_font_butt_1_size"
    android:textColor="@color/common_color_tl"
    android:background="@drawable/green_button"
    android:id="@+id/okButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Есть RelativeLayout с кнопкой внизу экрана. При тапе на editText выезжает клавиатура и кнопка перемещается над клавиатурой. Как сделать так, чтобы такого эффекта не было.

Comment: В этом RelativeLayout есть элементы, которые при этом нужно смещать при тапе на editText?

Comment: нет, таких элементов нет

Answer (score 2):

Нужно прописать в *AndroidManifest.xml* для активити такую строчку:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Клавиатура будет поверх разметки.
[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/146126/scrollview-edittext) обсуждалось похожее

Comment: а если это фрагмент, а не активити?

Comment: Фрагмент же включен в какое-либо активити.